# How to make div scrollable and with a height that doesn't causes the parent element to overflow?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In my app (using bootstrap 5.1 with react-bootstrap v2) I have a parent div to which I applied the style `max-height:100vh;` and `d-flex flex-column` classes. This parent div has 2 children:

1. A div containing a navbar;
2. A div with class `container-fluid and flex-grow-1`

Now if I apply the style `overflow:'auto';` at the container div it will become scrollable.
**My goal is to be able to build components that can expand their height automatically without causing parent div to overflow and scroll themselves instead**.

In the previous scenario I added `max-height:100vh;` and got a fixed parent height but I can't use this workaround in order to create such desired components.

I already tried setting height to 100% but it caused the parent element to overflow.

I made a [simple codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-framework-5mmlb?file=/src/App.js) with what I tried so far. Consider as target to get column 1 scrollable without scrolling other divs

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, you would like the Container element to stay at a static height based on viewport height and have components or divs that scroll within that constraint? If so I think this should work:

```html
import "./styles.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Navigator from "./Navigator";
import Content from "./Content";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-column w-100" >
      <div>
        <Navigator />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Container fluid>
          <div className="d-flex" style={{ height: "85vh" }}>
            <div className="px-2" style={{ overflow: "auto" }}>
              <h5>column 1</h5>
              <Content number={15} style={{ width: 200 }}>
                <p>.....................</p>
              </Content>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5>column 2</h5>
              <Content numeber={3} style={{ width: 200 }}>
                <p>-----------</p>
              </Content>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Container>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Navigator />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I used 85vh for the "d-flex" div height as an example as I don't know what height you have provided for the Navigator elements. The result is a static container height with column 1 scrolling instead of expanding the height of the containing div. If you don't have a set height for the navigator elements but still want the viewport to display all elements without scrolling you will need to use useEffect to query the height of those elements, post paint, and do a calculation based on viewport height to output the correct height for the container element.